# C++ String Expression Solver Running Into Access Violation

Tags: c++, error-handling, expression, access-violation

I am trying to create a program that will take in an expression (example: "10*2+1") and solve it. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void calculateString(std::string str);

int main() {

    calculateString("10*2+2");

    system("pause");
}

void calculateString(std::string str) {
    int total = 0;
    std::string temp1 = "";
    std::string temp2 = "";
    std::string add = "";
    std::string *ray = new std::string[str.length()];
    std::vector<int> newRay;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.at(i) != '*' && str.at(i) != '/' && str.at(i) != '+' && str.at(i) != '-') {
            add += str.at(i);
        }
        else {
            ray[i] = add;
            std::cout << ray[i] << "\n";
            add = "";
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (ray[i].compare("*")) {
            total = atoi(ray[i - 1].c_str()) * atoi(ray[i + 1].c_str());
            newRay.push_back(total);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (ray[i] == "+") {
            newRay.push_back(atoi(ray[i - 1].c_str()) + atoi(ray[i + 1].c_str()));
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < newRay.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << newRay[i] << "\n";
        total += newRay[i];
    }
    std::cout << str << "=" << total << "\n";
}
```

However, whenever I run this I keep running into an access violation error that reads:

> Exception thrown at 0x0F1CD4A0 (ucrtbased.dll) in CalcString.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01BE0FEE.

And it points to line 34 which is this: 
`total = atoi(ray[i - 1].c_str()) * atoi(ray[i + 1].c_str());`
which is basically calculating the multiplication part of the expression then storing the asnwer in one variable. I have tried everything from changing my array to a vector to trying to rewrite all the methods and nothing seems to work. Please help

Comment: Why ` std::string *ray = new std::string[str.length()];` (use a vector) Why the use of atoi()? (use stoi).

Comment: BTW, you don't need to initialize `std::string` variables with "", that is the initialization state.

Comment: I don't understand, you use `std::vector` for int, but not for `string`.  Why create the dynamic **array** of strings?

Comment: BTW, you can use operator == with strings, you don't need the `compare` method.

Comment: `ray[i - 1].c_str())` make darn sure `i!=0`

Comment: The most obviously possibility is that either `ray[i - 1]` or `ray[i + 1]` is going outside the bounds of the array. Debug your own code and see what values of `i` are being used there across the entire run of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
if (ray[i].compare("*"))
```

compare is misused. [According to cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare) `compare` returns < 0 for smaller than, 0 for equal or > 0 for larger.  As an `if` condition, 0 is false and everything else is true, so this resolves to

```
if (ray[i] != "*")
```

Probably the opposite of what is desired.

This allows entry into the `if`'s body when `ray[0]` is "10" and `i` is 0, resulting in

```
total = atoi(ray[0 - 1].c_str()) * atoi(ray[0 + 1].c_str());
```

or

```
total = atoi(ray[-1].c_str()) * atoi(ray[1].c_str());
```

and accessing negative array indexes is undefined behaviour. Looks like it manifested as a crash in this case.

Solution:

All we care about is equality in this case so we can get away with

```
if (ray[i] == "*")
```

just as was done for

```
if (ray[i] == "+")
```

I also recommend a check to ensure an operator is never the first element of `ray`.